# What is the IP address of my scanner?

Tags: scanner, sane, ip-address, xsane

I'm trying to configure and my scanner to work with SANE and some PDF software I'm trialling... But it needs the IP address of my locally (USB)-connected scanner (well, multi-function).

What's the command to identify this information?

Comment: Ok, it's resolved - but the question and answer do not really make sense now, right? And, they very much look like they make sense, because the real issue is not visible, and it's accepted. Looks like dead clutter in the collection of questions now, voting to close or delete.

Comment: Yeah, what @VolkerSiegel said - the question was wrong, I have a new (second) question that is now open and is actually correct this time 'round, so this question serves no purpose... Feel free to delete it.

Comment: Good, I can not delete it, I can ask someone - but maybe you can, at least vote to delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your multi-function device is connected by USB to your computer, then it does not have an IP address. You should try to configure in another way.

If your multi-function device has an Ethernet port (for network cable), and is connected to your local network (to the router), then it has an IP address. You can print the settings page of the device in order to find the IP address.

Comment: Never mind - I read the instructions wrong it's actually two IP addresses I need... I will give you the kudos though, because technically you answered this question correctly.